# Java spring ldap navigate into tree

Tags: java, treeview, tree, ldap, spring-ldap

In my ldap admin java program, i use dao classes to convert nodes into java class object.
Now my problem is to represent a tree view that is an organization chart for places (service, building, room, etc.) 
this organization chart will be use by users to select a work place in a form.

How can i proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to easylly represent tree items in front view : the plugin [jstree](https://www.jstree.com/)